# Runner Postman with list

Tags: postman

I'm struggling to make my runner works.
Here the raw body of my method

```
{
    "itemList": [
        "{{items}}"
    ],
    "storeType": 7,
    "storeNum": [
        "{{store}}"
    ]
}
```

i want to use a csv file containing line like this

store,items

115,"1097456,855591,716027"

The issue is, i don't know how to format the string i got from the file "1097456,855591,716027" to make my body works.

My body should look's like that:

```
{
    "itemList": [1097456,855591,716027],
    "storeType": 7,
    "storeNum": [115]
}
```

If i remove the double quote from "{{ITEMS}}" i got a json error.
I'm lost and start to think this is impossible :(

Any help is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Change the request body

```
{
    "itemList": {{items}},
    "storeType": 7,
    "storeNum": {{stores}}
}
```

Step 2: Write code in Pre-Request tab to convert String to a list of number.

```
let stores = readInput("store");
let items = readInput("item");

pm.environment.set("stores", JSON.stringify(stores));
pm.environment.set("items", JSON.stringify(items));

function readInput(header){
    let input = pm.iterationData.get(header).toString();
    let fields = [];

    if (input.includes(",")) {
        inputs = input.split(",");
        fields = inputs.map(x => parseInt(x));
    } else {
        fields.push(parseInt(input));
    }  
    return fields;
}
```

CSV file:

[image]

Sample request body:

[image]

Comment: Hello thank for your help but this is what i got when i don't use " on my variable: JSONError: Unexpected token 'i' at 2:19
    "itemList": {{items}},
                  ^

Comment: this is what is generated when i put the "        ```{
    "itemList": "[1097456,855591,716027]",
    "storeType": 7,
    "storeNum": "[115]"
}```

Comment: Pls, follow my instruction carefully. I don't understand your problem.